# Functional web chat

Tags: ruby, node.js, xmpp, chat

I want to build a website with a chat. The chat should have a calling option,stickers,smiley faces.Which language would you suggest and why?

- I`m thinking about ruby on rails or node.js
- I am also thinking to find someone who maybe have experience in the
  area, but i am not sure what kind of developer would suit me best.

Comment: This is Stack Overflow, so if you can't answer the basic "What have you tried?" question then it's premature to ask. Both Rails with [ActionCable](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2016/6/30/Rails-5-0-final/) and Node.js can do real-time chat. Both solutions *could* work. The way to find out what will work for you is to investigate both options.

Comment: This isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. There are many languages that will do what you want. It's for you to try them and see what fits best for your needs. Once you've tried writing code and encounter a problem with that code, THEN would be the time to ask a question about that particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language choice depends on how many hours you want to spend on development and further support.
Node.js is a simple and fast option if you want to build a working prototype. If you want to build something with a future advance (in order to solve such issues as scalability) and you have more time you can look at Golang and similar languages.